# solid shadow for CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer, shadow

I have an animated CALayer which is dropping a shadow. That is what I intended to do but I am looking for way to have a solid shadow without blur. Changing the blur radius does not save my problem.
Any ideas?

Many thanks.

```
    myLayer.shadowRadius = 3;
    //shadowBlurRadius
    myLayer.shadowColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    //intended is to get a green solid shadow without blur
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the myLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0? [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW84](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW84)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want no blurring, you can:

```
myLayer.shadowColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
myLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0);
myLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
myLayer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
```

The `shadowRadius` dictates the amount of blur. `shadowOffset` dictates where the shadow goes.

Comment: Thanks - setting the radius to 0.0 helped. In addition, I wanted to increase the shadow's radius - but not increase the blur (that is why I said changing the shadowRadius didn't work). Now that I have a solid shadow, I'll try to enlarge it using a bezier curve for the shadowPath of my layer.